# Inequality $\sqrt{\frac{(ab)^2+(bc)^2+(ca)^2}{a^4+b^4+c^4}}\Big(\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2}{7a+5b}\Big)+\frac{(a-b)^2}{12}\leq \frac{1}{12}$

Tags: inequality, radicals, buffalo-way

It take me a little bit of time to create this :

> > Let $a,b,c>0$ such that $a+b+c=1$ then we have :
> >     $$\sqrt{\frac{(ab)^2+(bc)^2+(ca)^2}{a^4+b^4+c^4}}\Big(\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2}{7a+5b}\Big)+\frac{(a-b)^2}{12}\leq \frac{1}{12}$$

First of all we have two equality case when $a=b=c=\frac{1}{3}$ and $a=1$

I have tried to delete the square root and after a full expanding to achieve with the Buffalo's ways.But I cannot conclude since we have negatives terms .I have not try Lagrange multiplier because I'm not familiar with this method but I think that the system resulting is awful .

If you are not convince that the inequality is true see [here (WA)](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=extrema%20calculator&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22GlobalExtremaCalculator%22%2C%20%22curvefunction%22%7D%20-%3E%22%28%28%28a%C2%B2b%C2%B2%29%C2%B2%2B%28b%C2%B2c%C2%B2%29%C2%B2%2B%28c%C2%B2a%C2%B2%29%C2%B2%29%2F%28a%5E8%2Bb%5E8%2Bc%5E8%29%29%5E%280.5%29%28a%5E4%2F%287a%C2%B2%2B5b%C2%B2%29%2Bb%5E4%2F%287b%C2%B2%2B5c%C2%B2%29%2Bc%5E4%2F%287c%C2%B2%2B5a%C2%B2%29%29%2B%28a%C2%B2-b%C2%B2%29%C2%B2%2F12%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22GlobalExtremaCalculator%22%2C%20%22domain%22%7D%20-%3E%22a%C2%B2%2Bb%C2%B2%2Bc%C2%B2%3D1%22)

If you have a trick (maybe with Cauchy-Schwarz) or a good answer I accept .

Thanks a lot to all .

Comment: I restored the original question.

Comment: @The.old.boy   It seems $\sqrt{\frac{(ab)^2+(bc)^2+(ca)^2}{a^4+b^4+c^4}}\Big(\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2}{7a+5b}\Big)+\frac{(a-b)^3}{12}\leq \frac{1}{12}$ is not true. Check $a = c = \frac{99}{200}, b = \frac{1}{100}$.

Comment: I went back to the original version; If you actually want to ask something else just ask a new question and link back.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's wrong.

Try $$(a,b,c)=\left(\frac{1}{12},\frac{11}{24},\frac{11}{24}\right).$$
In this case $$\frac{1}{12}-LHS=-0.000325...$$

Comment: Nice counterexample. I also checked it.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg   It seems the inequality is not yet true.

Comment: @River Li I think the second versa is true.